Do nonzero modules have finite grade?
In Bruns-Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay rings, Revised Edition, p.12 one finds the following definition:
Definition 1.2.11. Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $M \neq 0$ a finite $R$-module. Then the grade of $M$ is given by
$$ \text{grade } M = \min \{ i : \ \mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,R) \neq 0 \}.$$
For systematic reasons the grade of the zero module is infinity.
My interpretation of this definition is that if $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,R) = 0$ for all $i$, then $\text{grade } M = \infty$, although I also think that if such convention is in place then the case of $M =0$ should not be treated separately.
Therefore, I'd like to ask: under the assumptions of the definition above, can a nonzero module $M$ have infinite grade? That is, given a nonzero and finitely generated module $M$ over a Noetherian ring $R$, can it happen that $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,R) = 0$ for all $i$? If so, it would be ideal to have a characterization of such modules $M$, or at least an example.
Remark added later: on p. 25 of the same book it is stated that, since $\mathrm{Ext}^i(M,R)$ can be computed using a projective resolution of $M$, we have the bound $\text{grade } M \leq \text{proj dim } M$ (where I believe they forgot to mention the assumption $M \neq 0$). I can't justify this conclusion unless $\mathrm{grade } M < \infty$ is automatic at least for nonzero modules of finite projective dimension.

No. A nonzero finitely generated module always has finite grade. Reduce to the case when $M$ has finite length. Then show that for a module $N$ of depth $r$, $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)=0$ for $i<r$ and $\operatorname{Ext}^r(M,N)\neq0$.

@Mohan I see how to reduce to $R$ local and to $M$ of depth zero, but not how to reduce to dimension zero (hence finite length). Could you provide a hint?

Localize at a minimal prime in the support of $M$.

The question has basically been answered in comments by the user Mohan. Since comments can't be accepted as answers, I elaborate on the details below. Perhaps this is useful for someone in the future.
Proposition. Let $M$ be a Noetherian ring and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. If $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,R)=0$ for all $i$, then $M=0$.
Proof. Step 1: we reduce to the case of $R$ local and $\dim(M)=0$. Suppose that the statement is true under the additional assumptions. Let $M \neq 0$. There exists a minimal prime $\mathfrak p$ in the support of $M$. We have that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is local, $M_{\mathfrak p } \neq 0$ and $\dim(M_{\mathfrak p})=0$. Thus, by assumption, $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{R_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p},R_{\mathfrak p}) \neq 0$ for some $i$. Since for finitely generated modules over a Noetherian ring the Ext functors commute with localization, we get $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,R) \neq 0$.
Step 2. We prove the statement for $R$ local, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, and $M$ a (nonzero) module of Krull dimension zero. Since $\mathfrak m$ is the only prime ideal containing $\mathrm{Ann}(M)$, Proposition 1.2.10(a) in Bruns-Herzog guarantees existence of an $R$-regular sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathrm{Ann}(M)$ with $n=\mathrm{depth}(R)$. By the standard degree shifting argument (e.g. Lemma 1.2.4 in Bruns-Herzog) we have
$$ \mathrm{Ext}^n_R(M,R) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)). $$
Since $\mathrm{Ann}(M) \subset \mathfrak m$ and $\mathrm{depth}(R/(x_1,\dots,x_n))=0$, every element of $\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ acts as a zero divisor on $R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so (Proposition 1.2.3 in Bruns-Herzog) the Hom above is nonzero.
